# Converter in p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, selectonemenu

I have problem with my converter - it stops working and nothing happened.
I have Entity class "Group":

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_group")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean active = true;
    private String code;
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    // getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Group.id="+getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        System.out.println("OBJ :"+obj);
        if(obj == null )return false;
        if(obj instanceof String){
            if(obj.toString().equals(this.toString())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(obj instanceof Group){
            Group objGroup = (Group) obj;
            if(objGroup.getId() == this.getId()){
                System.out.println("EUREKA! Found");
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

here is my jsf view code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="group" value="#{priviligeMB.groupPrivilige.group}"  converter="#{groupConverter}" >  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{priviligeMB.groups}"  
                                    var="group" itemLabel="#{group.name}" itemValue="#{group}" />  
                    </p:selectOneMenu >
```

And of course GroupConverter class:

```
@Component("groupConverter")
public class GroupConverter implements Converter {

    @Autowired
    GroupService groupService;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        // arg2 is "Group.id=x" where x is just an id, for example "Group.id=2"
        try {
            System.out.println("getasObj: "+arg2);
            return groupService.getGroupById(Integer.parseInt(arg2.split("=")[1]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
       // arg2 is object with toString() method that prints: "Group.id=x"
        System.out.println("getAsString: "+arg2);
        return arg2.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my log:

```
> getAsString: Group.id=1 
> getAsString: Group.id=2 
> Hibernate: SELECT locale.code from messages_locale locale left join users_user u sers on
> users.locale_id = locale.id where users.username =? 
> getasObj: Group.id=1 
> Hibernate: select group0_.id as id0_0_, group0_.active as
> active0_0_, group0_.co de as code0_0_, group0_.name as name0_0_ from
> users_group group0_ where group0_. id=? 
> OBJ :Group.id=1 EUREKA! Found
> OBJ :Group.id=1 EUREKA! Found 
> OBJ :Group.id=2
```

And after that... nothing happened! No errors, no actions, no page reload, no messages...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nothing happened"? The value binding in the backing bean evaluates to null? the select menu is empty?

Comment: System doesn't response as if I didn't cklick the "save" button, no error stacktrase, no reloading on the page.

Comment: Then you probably have a conversion error. Confirm this by placing a `<h:messages/>` on your page and submitting your form

Comment: Same problem here - no stack trace (absolutely furious about this)

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem and finally it's solved.

In such case, you need to make sure the object returned by "**getAsObject**" can match one of the objects in `"#{priviligeMB.groups}"`, here "**match**" means the same object.